# Table cell width in IE7 with "table-layout: fixed" table

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a table I am using as a toolbar on a web page.  It works great in all browsers except for IE7.  The issue is that it expands the table to fit the contents (pushing the content off the screen) unless I specify "table-layout: fixed" in the CSS.  When I set the table layout to fixed it makes all the cells the same size, but I want them to size automatically to fit the content (and word wrap if needed).  Setting "width: auto" on the cell does not do anything.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table id="ToolbarTable" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td class="ToolbarCell" align="center">
            Button1
        </td>
        <td class="ToolbarCell" align="center">
            Button2 Button3 Button4
        </td>
        <td class="ToolbarCell" align="center">
            Button5 Button6 Button7 [Button8 Button9 - not always visible]
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
#ToolbarTable
{
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 24px;

    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#ToolbarTable td
{
    min-width: 50px;
    width: auto;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

In IE7, how can I make a table a specific width (and have IE7 honer it), while still letting the width of the table cells resize automatically?

EDIT: added code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I had spaces between the buttons I also had some `&nbsp;` spaces there and it was preventing the word wrap and causing the table width to exceed the width I specified.  Removing `&nbsp;` from between the buttons fixed the problem.  Each `&nbsp;` was surrounded by a space (I just wanted to add more space) and all other browsers were doing the line break correctly, but IE7 must either remove the extra spaces or assume they should be `&nbsp;` spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `min-width` in connection with a set `width`. I believe this combination should work with IE 7.

Comment: min-width does not seem to effect anything.  I can set the width, but I'd like it to automatically size it to the contents.

Comment: you would need to set the width to a numerical value for it to work in ie7. Auto wouldnt work. Does `width:50px;min-width:50px` give you the behavior you need?

Comment: No, it just makes the cell 50px wide.  I may have to use a javascript hack and calculate the size of each div, but it seems like a lot of work because I have to make sure I don't exceed the window's width and shrink all of the cells equally to make it fit if it does.

Comment: that does sound like too much work. good luck getting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a table width for the entire table.
And otherwise there's only one option, setting the table width's manually (easy to gather by using developer tools that most modern browsers include (IE8+, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, etc.), you can read the width's there). Otherwise I wouldn't know.

Comment: Yes, I could set manually, but sometimes more buttons are shown than other times and I don't want to recalculate the width of each cell according to the contents it has at that moment, I would just like IE7 to auto resize the cell and respect the table width :(

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know, IE gives me a lot of trouble too with styling. It always causes trouble.